# filter and get data from Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have this table:
[image: mysql table]

I need to get in an array all data from column "codigo" which has rows codidopostal = 1001. For this pourposse I am sending by "post" codigopostal = 1001.

[image: rest service]

Once I get it, then I need the first data from array to be extracted because later I will use it to add in an URI to make and query to an external server which have file in xml.

The uri I am building is:

"http://www.aemet.es/xml/municipios/localidad_01059.xml"

I make this.
http://www.aemet.es/xml/municipios/localidad_  + "0" + "codigo" + ".xml

but it do not add me "codigo". As it can be seen in photo, add only "0" but not "0" + "codigo".

[image: result]

Here I leave full code, any help will be welcome:

```
<?php

require_once 'login_mysql.php';

if(isset($_POST['postCode']) && !empty($_POST['postCode'])){

$sql = "SELECT alava.codigo FROM alava WHERE alava.codigopostal = '$postCode'";


if (mysqli_connect_error()){
    echo 'Error de Conexión: ' . mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
}

$r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
if (!$r){
    echo 'No se pudo hacer la consulta: ' . mysqli_error($con);
    echo json_encode("Registro inexistente");
    exit();
}

$result = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)){

    //Pushing name and id in the blank array created
    array_push($result,array(
        "codigo"=>$row['codigo']

        ));
    $codigo = array_values($result)[0];
}

  echo json_encode(array('result'=>$output_result));

// Close mysql connection
mysqli_close($con);

    }else{
     echo "Operacion fallida";
    }

$json_object = json_decode( json_encode(array('result'=>$result)) );


$localidad = "$codigo";
$cadena1 = "http://www.aemet.es/xml/municipios/localidad_";
$cadena2 = "$localidad";
$cadena3 = ".xml";
$prefijo = "0";
$url=$cadena1 . $prefijo . $cadena2 . $cadena3 ;


$texto = file_get_contents($url);
$texto = str_replace(array("\n", "\r", "\t"), '', $texto);
$texto = trim(str_replace('"', "'", $texto));
$simpleXml = simplexml_load_string($texto);
$json = json_encode($simpleXml);
echo $json;

return $json;
```

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: where is the if condition for echo "Operacion fallida";

Comment: I Marc, I am just making a trial. Not final code. Only traying to understand how it works.

Comment: Hi Cyckitron, It do not shows it because it is working but for some reasson, not sending it  to "$localidad = "$codigo""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution-

First query correctly to table extracting all data with specific index. In this case is "codigopostal.

```
require_once 'login_mysql.php';


if(isset($_POST['postCode']) && !empty($_POST['postCode'])){
$postCode = $_POST['postCode'];

 $sql =
       "SELECT * FROM wp_alava WHERE wp_alava.codigopostal = '$postCode'";
```

Then we take data and we input it in array. Once it is inside, then we take the first one, since all are duplicated and we only need one, and because we do not know how many there are, we are sure that there is one which is the first one.

```
    //creating a blank array
 $result = array();

//looping through all the records fetched
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)){


 array_push($result,array(
//Pushing codigo in the blank array created
        "codigo"=>$row['codigo']
    ));
}

//Displaying the array in json format
 $codigo_poblacion = json_encode(array('result'=>$result));

 $primer_codigo_encontrado = json_decode($codigo_poblacion);

 $primer_codigo_encontrado->result[0]->codigo;
 $codigo_poblacion_aemet = $primer_codigo_encontrado->result[0]->codigo;
```

then we build our URI and send it geting data. Because data we need in Json, we parse it inrto JSon Format in order to be used later in our APP or any other User Interface.

That is all, here you have an API to build an URI for Spanish Weather Web which did not give it, they only give you XML for forecasts.

Regards